# How to remove object from axios proxy array

Tags: axios, vuejs3

The below is slightly simplified...
The Axios request returns data like this:

```
Proxy {0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Array(3)
0: {code: "AAA", id: "001", label: "Foo"}
1: {code: "BBB", id: "002", label: "Bar"}
2: {code: "CCC", id: "003", label: "Baz"}
```

I am trying to remove any objects from this which match items in my array:

```
var reqData = this.requestData;
var myArr = ["Foo", "Bar"];
    
for (let index = 0; index < myArr.length; ++index) {   
    reqData = reqData.filter(function( obj ) {
        return obj.label !== myArr[index];
    });
}
```

This works, to a degree. It produces the following:

```
(1) [Proxy]
0: Proxy {code: "CCC" id: "003", label: "Baz"}
```

However this data does not output in the vue HTML. I notice the structure has changed and no longer shows Handler and Target.

Answer (score 0):

Push the reqData items to an array

```
      var testarr = [];
      for (let index = 0; index < reqData.length; ++index) {   
            testarr.push({label: reqData[index].label, id: reqData[index].id, code: reqData[index].code });
      }
```

rebuild proxy object

```
  var proxy = new Proxy( testarr, {} );
```